# Mongo db requests not hash Based

Tags: mongodb, firebase, indexing

New to Nosql DB offline but experimented with Firebase real Time Database.
It intend to build a large db for which a nosql struture is likely more appropriated .
In Firebase style , i intend to make requests : myRef.child(k).child(j).getvalue()
K and j are strings based on integer . On Firebase , time to make the request is more or less constant (i m talking about large db) .
Using MongoDB, i start populate the db with small values of j and k .
When i make requests , low values with be fast to retrieve while higher value will be extremely slow at a point it is impossible to use this db ;
As i understood, this might be linked to the hash value that is "ordered" while this should n t be the case .
My question : is there a way to optimize requests in MongoDB to suit my case ?
If no, is there another offline db that works similar to Firebase real Time database(couch db) ?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Real Time Database is giant JSON tree while MongoDb is a full blown database with collections and documents. A more accurate parallel will be comparing mongoDb with firestore.
In order to make mongo "fast" you can do two things:

1. Data Modelling: Unlike Realtime Db, you can spilt the database into multiple collections (tables) and use associations. This is purely based on your use case.
2. Use indexes: Mongo uses indexes to make reads faster. You can apply indexes on field which you intent to use as filter for fetching data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . It is a bit  clearer now . Is there another DB type (offline) that works similar to real time database ?